# '.', <column alias name>, <compound operator>, AS, BETWEEN, FROM, GROUP, IN, LIMIT, ORDER, WHERE, comma or semicolon expected, got 'SELECT'

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Please I need help fixing the error above _ in the title _ appeared in the first SELECT after FROM of this query, all suggestions are welcome so thank you very much.

```
       public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAll_Datas() {
    
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListAllData = new 
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery 

       (
        " SELECT lespontes.idPontes ,\n" +
        "  lespontes.Cage as Cage,\n" +
        " lespontes.Couvés,\n" +
        " dbfécondation.Fécondés " + "FROM " +
        (
                " SELECT idPontes FROM lespontes"+
                        " UNION "
                        + " SELECT idPontes FROM dbfécondation" ) +
        " LEFT OUTER JOIN"
        + " lespontes USING (idPontes)"+
        " LEFT OUTER JOIN "
        + " dbfécondation USING (idPontes)"+
        " Order By " +  " lespontes.Cage " + " ASC ",null);
    
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMapData= new HashMap<String, 
        String>();
    
        hashMapData.put("idPontes", cursor.getString(0));
        hashMapData.put("Cage",cursor.getString(1));
        hashMapData.put("Couvés",cursor.getString(2));
        hashMapData.put("Fécondés", cursor.getString(3));

        arrayListAllData.add(hashMapData);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return arrayListAllData;
        }
```

Comment: did you really meant `... "FROM " + ( " SELECT  ...`?  that parenthesis is pretty *strange* (same for the closing one) - shouldn't it be part of the SQL (String)? that is `... "FROM " + "(" + " SELECT  ...`

Comment: Try writing your SQL as one string.

Comment: Yes , this SELECT  which is underlined in red

Comment: No ,this parenthesis is not strange ,I tried the query in SQLITE STUDIO and it  works.

Comment: I test the query  in SQLITE STUDIO  without String like this:   SELECT lespontes.idPontes ,
                lespontes.Cage as Cage,
                lespontes.Couvés,
                dbfécondation.Fécondés FROM
                (
                SELECT idPontes FROM lespontes
                UNION
                SELECT idPontes FROM dbfécondation )
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                lespontes USING (idPontes)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbfécondation USING (idPontes)
                Order By  +  lespontes.Cage ASC

Comment: It's true there is a big difference between the two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :-

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery

          (
                  " SELECT lespontes.idPontes ," +
                          "  lespontes.Cage as Cage," +
                          " lespontes.Couvés," +
                          " dbfécondation.Fécondés " + "FROM (" +
                                  " SELECT idPontes FROM lespontes" +
                                          " UNION "
                                          + " SELECT idPontes FROM dbfécondation)" +
                          " LEFT OUTER JOIN"
                          + " lespontes USING (idPontes)" +
                          " LEFT OUTER JOIN "
                          + " dbfécondation USING (idPontes)" +
                          " Order By " + " lespontes.Cage " + " ASC ", null);
```

i.e. the parenthesises surrounding the SELECT have been embedded within the SQL. Also the useless line feeds (`\n`'s) have also been removed.

Comment: Your suggestion is very helpful and solved my problem, the default was in those  parenthesises, so thank you very much.